# More tag didn't display "read more" Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

This code display 3 recents posts, whit post thumbnails etc. When I manually break te text with "more" tag, it display the text only to this place, but without "read more". Which paramets should I edit?

```
 <!-- LOOP START -->
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'showposts=3&cat=4' ); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
    <!-- THIS DISPLAYS THE POST THUMBNAIL, The array allows the image to has a custom size but is always kept proportional -->
      <div id="hotele"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"> <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(349,349) );?></a>
      <!-- THIS DISPLAYS THE POST TITLE AS A LINK TO THE MAIN POST -->
      <div><h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2></div>
      <!-- THIS DISPLAYS THE EXCERPT OF THE POST -->
      <li><?php the_excerpt(); ?></li>
      </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>
<!-- LOOP FINNISH -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`the_excerpt()`  will display 40 character and at the end you can display  ready more link with permalink to  actual single post page  like  `<a href="<?php the_permalink()?>">Read More</a>`